# Threejs texture map to sphere error (three.min.js:120 THREE.WebGLRenderer: image is not power of two (1000x500))

Tags: three.js, texture-mapping

I am learning three js now. What I am trying to do now is draw a sphere and then texture map an image on the sphere. Basically, I am following this tutorial, http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2013/09/16/how-to-make-the-earth-in-webgl/.

This is my code

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/93/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var scene = new THREE.Scene();
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

  window.addEventListener('resize', function() {

    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    renderer.setSize(width, height);
    camera.aspect = width / height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  })

  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);


  var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.5, 32, 32)
  var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();

  var earthMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
  scene.add(earthMesh)

  // TheJim01: Replacing local file with accessible web resource
  // License and source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Earthmap1000x500compac.jpg
  //material.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("world.jpg");
  material.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/Earthmap1000x500compac.jpg");
  camera.position.z = 10; //3


  //game logic
  var update = function() {

  };

  //draw scene
  var render = function() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }

  // run game loop (update, render, repeat)
  var GameLoop = function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(GameLoop);

    update();
    render();
  }

  GameLoop();
</script>
```

When I run the code, I got this error in the console.

```
three.min.js:120 THREE.WebGLRenderer: image is not power of two (1000x500)
```

My image file actually have 1000X500 size as well. But nothing is displayed on the canvas. What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: The "error" you're seeing isn't an error, it's a _warning_. Textures should have dimensions in power-of-two scales (e.g. `64x128`). If your texture does NOT have power-of-two dimensions, you'll see this _warning_, and three.js will do the necessary scaling in the background to make it fit.

Comment: But why it is not displaying anything?? When I add a simple cube it is displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to load the texture without errors (in three.js r93) with `THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture`. It threw a "tainted canvas" error in Chrome. I switched to using [`THREE.TextureLoader`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/loaders/TextureLoader), which you can see in the code below.

All that said, that was probably not the *real* problem. Your scene is lacking a light, and without a light, everything will render as black. In the code below, I added a simple point light to the camera.

With those two fixes in place, your code runs as expected.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/93/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var scene = new THREE.Scene();
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

  window.addEventListener('resize', function() {

    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    renderer.setSize(width, height);
    camera.aspect = width / height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  })

  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  
  scene.add(camera);
  camera.add(new THREE.PointLight(0xfffff, 1, Infinity));


  var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.5, 32, 32)
  var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();

  var earthMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
  scene.add(earthMesh)

  // TheJim01: Replacing local file with accessible web resource
  // License and source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Earthmap1000x500compac.jpg
  //material.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("world.jpg");
  var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
  material.map = loader.load("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/Earthmap1000x500compac.jpg");
  camera.position.z = 10; //3


  //game logic
  var update = function() {

  };

  //draw scene
  var render = function() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }

  // run game loop (update, render, repeat)
  var GameLoop = function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(GameLoop);

    update();
    render();
  }

  GameLoop();
</script>
```